# Is Prism Primarily for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, prism, lob, prism-4

The majority of the articles/tutorials/blog post I read about Microsoft's Prism Framework center around Silverlight. With the composite model being an interesting model for an existing desktop app that needs a little TLC, I'm wondering is Prism a viable technology for a desktop LOB app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for `Silverlight(Web)`, `WPF(Desktop)` and `Windows Phone 7(Phone)`.

Basically, it is for any platform that uses `XAML`, `MVVM` combo.

And for your last question, **YES**, it's a very good option to go with when developing a `LOB` application in `WPF`.

But remember, you will need to spend a few days just to learn `Prism` (and `Unity` or `MEF`). So, be ready for it.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, the majority of the stuff I'm finding is for silverlight. As a follow up question, How close do the silverlight side of things follow the the desktop the desktop side?

Comment: Pretty close. In fact, `WPF` being more featurep-rich in most areas, `Prism for WPF` offers a few more features than other versions.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, Solutions of Prism for `WPF` and `Silverlight` share a lot many common projects/code.

Answer (score 1):

most of the online resources are for Silverlight because it wasn't until fairly recently that WPF support was officially released.   Prism 4.0 at http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/ includes WPF resources including some on sharing code between WPF & SL